# postgres find age range with no of minutes of different user to watch channels

Tags: postgresql

I have two table 1000 of record given below.

My first table is USER table.

```
    ID         Name             DateOfBirth 
    1          John             1980-11-20 00:00:00.000
    2          Denial           1940-04-10 00:00:00.000
    3          Binney           1995-12-25 00:00:00.000
    4          Sara             1960-11-20 00:00:00.000
    5          Poma             1980-11-20 00:00:00.000
    6          Cameroon         1980-11-20 00:00:00.000
    .....
    .....
```

And my second table is CHANNEL_WATCH_DURATION_BY_USER

```
userid       duration   channelname
1            100         SAB
2            200         zee Tv
1            400         axn
2            0           star 1
3            800         star 2
3            700         star 3
4            200         star 4
.....
.....
```

I need to write the POSTGRES SQL Query to display different age groups contain duration  with each channel.

```
under 18     20-30 age    30-40 age    chaneel
10             40          100         star 1
20             0           200         star 2
30             79          0           zee
40             80          30          axn
.....
.....
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: you have to use `case when` condition for this

Comment: Is Denial in denial?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I already done by php side but I trying to get record from mysql.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),DateOfBirth)<18,1,0)) AS under18,
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 20 AND 30,1,0)) as 20_to_30_age,
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),DateOfBirth)BETWEEN 30 AND 40,1,0)) as 30_to_40_age,
channelname as chaneel from 
USER a,CHANNEL_WATCH_DURATION_BY_USER b where a.ID=b.USERID GROUP BY channelname
```